# call name of method contained in a string

Tags: groovy

How can I call a method based on the value of a string in Groovy? For example instead of

```
switch (val) {
case "one":
    Obj.one()
    break
case "two":
    Obj.two()
    break
}
```

I’d like to do something like `obj.val` where `val` contains either "*one"* or *"two"* instead of a case statement.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

[Dynamic method invocation](http://www.groovy-lang.org/metaprogramming.html#_dynamic_method_names) looks like this

```
obj."$val"()
```

Comment: The provided link is dead.  This one might cover the topic:

http://www.groovy-lang.org/metaprogramming.html#_dynamic_method_names

Comment: The revised link points to the wrong feature (creating methods dynamically rather than calling them dynamically).

Comment: And what to do if the obj is dynamic too?

Comment: @NikolaiEhrhardt Um... it already is? obj is a variable, in what way would you want it to be more dynamic?

Comment: being in a groovy file, you can refer with this.* to every function or variable. and now imagine second groovy file xyz and you want to call function from there: xyz.echoxyz(). and you know string "xyz.echoxyz" how to call this. from my experience if val="xyz.echoxyz" doing "$val"() doesnt work.