# groovy call method name contains special character

Tags: groovy

I'd like to call a method which name contains space in static context, but it do not work. 
Any suggestions?

```
class Test2 { 
    void "test"() {
        "test a"()
    }

    void "test a"() { 
        println "test a" 
    } 

    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        def t = new Test2() 
        t."test"() //it works
        t."test a"()  //raise error,  Illegal class name "Test2$test a" in class file Test2$test a 
    } 
} 

G:\tmp\groovy\gp1\src>groovy -version 
Groovy Version: 2.3.2 JVM: 1.7.0_02 Vendor: Oracle Corporation OS: Windows 7 

G:\tmp\groovy\gp1\src>groovy Test2.groovy 
Test1.main 
Caught: java.lang.ClassFormatError: Illegal class name "Test2$test a" in class file Test2$test a 
java.lang.ClassFormatError: Illegal class name "Test2$test a" in class file Test2$test a 
        at Test2.main(Test2.groovy:15)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about `invokeMethod`?

```
class Invokes { 

    def "test a"() { 
        "test a" 
    } 

    static main(args) { 
        def t = new Invokes() 
        assert t.invokeMethod("test a", null) == "test a" 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It will work this way:

```
class Test2 { 

    void "test a"() { 
        println "test a" 
    } 

    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        def t = new Test2() 
        def v = 'test a'
        t."$v"()
    } 
}
```

As described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357800/call-name-of-method-contained-in-a-string) and [here](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2010/03/groovy-goodness-invoke-methods.html), but no idea why Your example doesn't work.

Comment: I think it's the static context, adding a `void run()` method that calls `this.'test a'()` works as well when the `main` method calls `t.run()`

Comment: @tim_yates curiously, this doesn't work: `static main(args) { def t = new Invokes(); t.run(t) } def run(self) { self."test a"() }`